# How to change fill color of SVG dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I am trying to change the fill color of my SVG when it is selected and active. One color for its active state and another for when not.

So far I have been trying to add and remove classes (using jQuery) to my SVG's path in order for the classes to change when the element is clicked.

I've tried adding a class to the path attribute I named `nav-item nav-item-background`that is the normal state and I added the default active state called `.nav-item-active .nav-item-background` to the parent li

To switch between these two classes I'm trying to use jQuery. I've tried using addClass() and removeClass() methods, and with further research I've found posts from about two years ago that say you need to update jQuery for those to work. I've updated to 3.4.1 and those classes still aren't changing.

I also tried using the attr('class' "class1 class2") approach, and no dice either.

Anyways, I've already tried research for many hours on this, and I've seem to have hit a wall. Many of the posts on the subject are also kinda old. Or I'm just mind f'kd.

Could I possibly be targeting the wrong thing? Should the class `nav-item-background` not be in the path of the SVG?

Check my code out pls

```js
$('.nav-container li a').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.parent('li').addClass('nav-item-background').siblings('li').removeClass('nav-item-active');
});
```

```css
.nav-item .nav-item-background {
  fill: blue;
}

.nav-item-active .nav-item-background {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-container">
  <li class="nav-item nav-item-active">
    <a href="#0">
      <span>Home</span>
      <span>
<svg class"nav-item-background" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0, 0, 400,400"><g id="svgg"><path class="nav-item-background" id="path0" d="M147.519 178.219 L 146.438 178.806 146.319 196.789 C 146.181 217.583,146.506 216.053,142.170 216.330 C 137.245 216.643,136.400 215.403,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 201.519,136.770 201.840,129.244 201.660 C 120.081 201.441,120.075 201.449,120.517 213.783 C 120.847 222.981,122.318 226.144,127.469 228.726 C 134.482 232.241,150.057 232.147,156.608 228.550 C 163.323 224.863,163.600 223.682,163.600 198.702 L 163.600 179.564 162.618 178.582 C 161.399 177.363,149.618 177.080,147.519 178.219 M173.739 177.877 C 172.023 178.213,171.928 179.325,172.106 197.058 L 172.274 213.800 173.489 217.427 C 174.157 219.422,174.971 221.582,175.298 222.227 C 175.625 222.872,176.010 224.030,176.154 224.800 C 176.297 225.570,176.952 227.055,177.608 228.100 L 178.801 230.000 185.124 230.000 C 192.778 230.000,193.173 229.796,194.199 225.318 C 194.491 224.043,194.998 222.190,195.325 221.200 C 195.653 220.210,196.113 218.676,196.349 217.792 C 196.771 216.208,198.856 214.721,199.407 215.612 C 199.810 216.263,201.643 222.159,202.069 224.174 C 202.530 226.354,203.329 228.180,204.310 229.300 C 204.846 229.911,205.725 230.000,211.228 230.000 L 217.533 230.000 218.716 228.500 C 219.367 227.675,220.033 226.370,220.197 225.600 C 220.361 224.830,220.695 223.840,220.939 223.400 C 221.737 221.963,223.634 216.247,223.992 214.200 C 224.778 209.701,224.477 178.994,223.639 178.235 C 222.639 177.330,209.768 177.428,208.660 178.349 C 208.074 178.836,207.998 180.234,207.986 190.749 C 207.975 199.895,207.849 202.821,207.435 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 206.611 203.569 C 204.769 197.349,202.542 195.383,197.691 195.694 C 194.219 195.917,193.307 196.580,191.983 199.842 C 191.044 202.157,190.904 202.268,189.897 201.500 C 189.322 201.062,189.226 199.640,189.120 190.064 L 189.000 179.128 188.056 178.364 C 187.147 177.629,176.809 177.277,173.739 177.877 M234.373 178.233 C 233.536 179.241,233.513 228.332,234.349 229.339 C 234.844 229.935,236.605 230.000,252.360 230.000 L 269.823 230.000 272.641 228.649 C 277.851 226.152,278.543 224.243,278.334 212.929 C 278.178 204.508,278.085 204.270,273.702 201.043 L 271.215 199.213 272.183 197.787 C 276.427 191.533,273.913 181.449,267.378 178.516 C 264.969 177.435,235.247 177.180,234.373 178.233 M257.685 190.546 C 259.049 191.582,259.103 195.639,257.771 196.972 C 256.863 197.879,250.991 197.876,250.643 196.967 C 250.205 195.825,250.382 190.978,250.880 190.480 C 251.537 189.823,256.801 189.874,257.685 190.546 M261.463 210.219 C 262.188 211.210,262.167 215.618,261.433 216.624 C 260.703 217.623,251.345 218.071,250.751 217.135 C 250.336 216.479,250.299 210.777,250.706 210.140 C 251.474 208.940,260.576 209.006,261.463 210.219 " stroke="none" fill="#f4f4f4" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path1" d="M19.200 200.000 L 19.200 298.800 200.000 298.800 L 380.800 298.800 380.800 200.000 L 380.800 101.200 200.000 101.200 L 19.200 101.200 19.200 200.000 M162.618 178.582 L 163.600 179.564 163.600 198.702 C 163.600 223.682,163.323 224.863,156.608 228.550 C 150.057 232.147,134.482 232.241,127.469 228.726 C 122.318 226.144,120.847 222.981,120.517 213.783 C 120.075 201.449,120.081 201.441,129.244 201.660 C 136.770 201.840,136.400 201.519,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 215.403,137.245 216.643,142.170 216.330 C 146.506 216.053,146.181 217.583,146.319 196.789 L 146.438 178.806 147.519 178.219 C 149.618 177.080,161.399 177.363,162.618 178.582 M188.056 178.364 L 189.000 179.128 189.120 190.064 C 189.226 199.640,189.322 201.062,189.897 201.500 C 190.904 202.268,191.044 202.157,191.983 199.842 C 193.307 196.580,194.219 195.917,197.691 195.694 C 202.542 195.383,204.769 197.349,206.611 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 207.435 203.569 C 207.849 202.821,207.975 199.895,207.986 190.749 C 207.998 180.234,208.074 178.836,208.660 178.349 C 209.768 177.428,222.639 177.330,223.639 178.235 C 224.477 178.994,224.778 209.701,223.992 214.200 C 223.634 216.247,221.737 221.963,220.939 223.400 C 220.695 223.840,220.361 224.830,220.197 225.600 C 220.033 226.370,219.367 227.675,218.716 228.500 L 217.533 230.000 211.228 230.000 C 205.725 230.000,204.846 229.911,204.310 229.300 C 203.329 228.180,202.530 226.354,202.069 224.174 C 201.643 222.159,199.810 216.263,199.407 215.612 C 198.856 214.721,196.771 216.208,196.349 217.792 C 196.113 218.676,195.653 220.210,195.325 221.200 C 194.998 222.190,194.491 224.043,194.199 225.318 C 193.173 229.796,192.778 230.000,185.124 230.000 L 178.801 230.000 177.608 228.100 C 176.952 227.055,176.297 225.570,176.154 224.800 C 176.010 224.030,175.625 222.872,175.298 222.227 C 174.971 221.582,174.157 219.422,173.489 217.427 L 172.274 213.800 172.106 197.058 C 171.928 179.325,172.023 178.213,173.739 177.877 C 176.809 177.277,187.147 177.629,188.056 178.364 M267.378 178.516 C 273.913 181.449,276.427 191.533,272.183 197.787 L 271.215 199.213 273.702 201.043 C 278.085 204.270,278.178 204.508,278.334 212.929 C 278.543 224.243,277.851 226.152,272.641 228.649 L 269.823 230.000 252.360 230.000 C 236.605 230.000,234.844 229.935,234.349 229.339 C 233.513 228.332,233.536 179.241,234.373 178.233 C 235.247 177.180,264.969 177.435,267.378 178.516 M250.880 190.480 C 250.382 190.978,250.205 195.825,250.643 196.967 C 250.991 197.876,256.863 197.879,257.771 196.972 C 259.103 195.639,259.049 191.582,257.685 190.546 C 256.801 189.874,251.537 189.823,250.880 190.480 M252.000 209.470 C 250.586 209.768,250.412 210.219,250.412 213.600 C 250.412 217.817,250.237 217.693,255.978 217.535 C 261.781 217.375,262.000 217.224,262.000 213.400 C 262.000 209.745,261.702 209.506,256.963 209.372 C 254.783 209.311,252.550 209.355,252.000 209.470 " stroke="none" fill="#040404" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `toggleClass()` on the parent element.

```js
$('.nav-container li a').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.parent().toggleClass('nav-item-active').siblings().removeClass('nav-item-active');
});
```

```css
.nav-item .nav-item-background {
  fill: blue;
}

.nav-item-active .nav-item-background {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-container">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#0">
      <span>Home</span>
      <span>
<svg class"nav-item-background" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0, 0, 400,400"><g id="svgg"><path class="nav-item-background" id="path0" d="M147.519 178.219 L 146.438 178.806 146.319 196.789 C 146.181 217.583,146.506 216.053,142.170 216.330 C 137.245 216.643,136.400 215.403,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 201.519,136.770 201.840,129.244 201.660 C 120.081 201.441,120.075 201.449,120.517 213.783 C 120.847 222.981,122.318 226.144,127.469 228.726 C 134.482 232.241,150.057 232.147,156.608 228.550 C 163.323 224.863,163.600 223.682,163.600 198.702 L 163.600 179.564 162.618 178.582 C 161.399 177.363,149.618 177.080,147.519 178.219 M173.739 177.877 C 172.023 178.213,171.928 179.325,172.106 197.058 L 172.274 213.800 173.489 217.427 C 174.157 219.422,174.971 221.582,175.298 222.227 C 175.625 222.872,176.010 224.030,176.154 224.800 C 176.297 225.570,176.952 227.055,177.608 228.100 L 178.801 230.000 185.124 230.000 C 192.778 230.000,193.173 229.796,194.199 225.318 C 194.491 224.043,194.998 222.190,195.325 221.200 C 195.653 220.210,196.113 218.676,196.349 217.792 C 196.771 216.208,198.856 214.721,199.407 215.612 C 199.810 216.263,201.643 222.159,202.069 224.174 C 202.530 226.354,203.329 228.180,204.310 229.300 C 204.846 229.911,205.725 230.000,211.228 230.000 L 217.533 230.000 218.716 228.500 C 219.367 227.675,220.033 226.370,220.197 225.600 C 220.361 224.830,220.695 223.840,220.939 223.400 C 221.737 221.963,223.634 216.247,223.992 214.200 C 224.778 209.701,224.477 178.994,223.639 178.235 C 222.639 177.330,209.768 177.428,208.660 178.349 C 208.074 178.836,207.998 180.234,207.986 190.749 C 207.975 199.895,207.849 202.821,207.435 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 206.611 203.569 C 204.769 197.349,202.542 195.383,197.691 195.694 C 194.219 195.917,193.307 196.580,191.983 199.842 C 191.044 202.157,190.904 202.268,189.897 201.500 C 189.322 201.062,189.226 199.640,189.120 190.064 L 189.000 179.128 188.056 178.364 C 187.147 177.629,176.809 177.277,173.739 177.877 M234.373 178.233 C 233.536 179.241,233.513 228.332,234.349 229.339 C 234.844 229.935,236.605 230.000,252.360 230.000 L 269.823 230.000 272.641 228.649 C 277.851 226.152,278.543 224.243,278.334 212.929 C 278.178 204.508,278.085 204.270,273.702 201.043 L 271.215 199.213 272.183 197.787 C 276.427 191.533,273.913 181.449,267.378 178.516 C 264.969 177.435,235.247 177.180,234.373 178.233 M257.685 190.546 C 259.049 191.582,259.103 195.639,257.771 196.972 C 256.863 197.879,250.991 197.876,250.643 196.967 C 250.205 195.825,250.382 190.978,250.880 190.480 C 251.537 189.823,256.801 189.874,257.685 190.546 M261.463 210.219 C 262.188 211.210,262.167 215.618,261.433 216.624 C 260.703 217.623,251.345 218.071,250.751 217.135 C 250.336 216.479,250.299 210.777,250.706 210.140 C 251.474 208.940,260.576 209.006,261.463 210.219 " stroke="none" fill="#f4f4f4" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path1" d="M19.200 200.000 L 19.200 298.800 200.000 298.800 L 380.800 298.800 380.800 200.000 L 380.800 101.200 200.000 101.200 L 19.200 101.200 19.200 200.000 M162.618 178.582 L 163.600 179.564 163.600 198.702 C 163.600 223.682,163.323 224.863,156.608 228.550 C 150.057 232.147,134.482 232.241,127.469 228.726 C 122.318 226.144,120.847 222.981,120.517 213.783 C 120.075 201.449,120.081 201.441,129.244 201.660 C 136.770 201.840,136.400 201.519,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 215.403,137.245 216.643,142.170 216.330 C 146.506 216.053,146.181 217.583,146.319 196.789 L 146.438 178.806 147.519 178.219 C 149.618 177.080,161.399 177.363,162.618 178.582 M188.056 178.364 L 189.000 179.128 189.120 190.064 C 189.226 199.640,189.322 201.062,189.897 201.500 C 190.904 202.268,191.044 202.157,191.983 199.842 C 193.307 196.580,194.219 195.917,197.691 195.694 C 202.542 195.383,204.769 197.349,206.611 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 207.435 203.569 C 207.849 202.821,207.975 199.895,207.986 190.749 C 207.998 180.234,208.074 178.836,208.660 178.349 C 209.768 177.428,222.639 177.330,223.639 178.235 C 224.477 178.994,224.778 209.701,223.992 214.200 C 223.634 216.247,221.737 221.963,220.939 223.400 C 220.695 223.840,220.361 224.830,220.197 225.600 C 220.033 226.370,219.367 227.675,218.716 228.500 L 217.533 230.000 211.228 230.000 C 205.725 230.000,204.846 229.911,204.310 229.300 C 203.329 228.180,202.530 226.354,202.069 224.174 C 201.643 222.159,199.810 216.263,199.407 215.612 C 198.856 214.721,196.771 216.208,196.349 217.792 C 196.113 218.676,195.653 220.210,195.325 221.200 C 194.998 222.190,194.491 224.043,194.199 225.318 C 193.173 229.796,192.778 230.000,185.124 230.000 L 178.801 230.000 177.608 228.100 C 176.952 227.055,176.297 225.570,176.154 224.800 C 176.010 224.030,175.625 222.872,175.298 222.227 C 174.971 221.582,174.157 219.422,173.489 217.427 L 172.274 213.800 172.106 197.058 C 171.928 179.325,172.023 178.213,173.739 177.877 C 176.809 177.277,187.147 177.629,188.056 178.364 M267.378 178.516 C 273.913 181.449,276.427 191.533,272.183 197.787 L 271.215 199.213 273.702 201.043 C 278.085 204.270,278.178 204.508,278.334 212.929 C 278.543 224.243,277.851 226.152,272.641 228.649 L 269.823 230.000 252.360 230.000 C 236.605 230.000,234.844 229.935,234.349 229.339 C 233.513 228.332,233.536 179.241,234.373 178.233 C 235.247 177.180,264.969 177.435,267.378 178.516 M250.880 190.480 C 250.382 190.978,250.205 195.825,250.643 196.967 C 250.991 197.876,256.863 197.879,257.771 196.972 C 259.103 195.639,259.049 191.582,257.685 190.546 C 256.801 189.874,251.537 189.823,250.880 190.480 M252.000 209.470 C 250.586 209.768,250.412 210.219,250.412 213.600 C 250.412 217.817,250.237 217.693,255.978 217.535 C 261.781 217.375,262.000 217.224,262.000 213.400 C 262.000 209.745,261.702 209.506,256.963 209.372 C 254.783 209.311,252.550 209.355,252.000 209.470 " stroke="none" fill="#040404" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li> 
  <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#0">
          <span>About</span>
          <span>
    <svg class"nav-item-background" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0, 0, 400,400"><g id="svgg"><path class="nav-item-background" id="path0" d="M147.519 178.219 L 146.438 178.806 146.319 196.789 C 146.181 217.583,146.506 216.053,142.170 216.330 C 137.245 216.643,136.400 215.403,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 201.519,136.770 201.840,129.244 201.660 C 120.081 201.441,120.075 201.449,120.517 213.783 C 120.847 222.981,122.318 226.144,127.469 228.726 C 134.482 232.241,150.057 232.147,156.608 228.550 C 163.323 224.863,163.600 223.682,163.600 198.702 L 163.600 179.564 162.618 178.582 C 161.399 177.363,149.618 177.080,147.519 178.219 M173.739 177.877 C 172.023 178.213,171.928 179.325,172.106 197.058 L 172.274 213.800 173.489 217.427 C 174.157 219.422,174.971 221.582,175.298 222.227 C 175.625 222.872,176.010 224.030,176.154 224.800 C 176.297 225.570,176.952 227.055,177.608 228.100 L 178.801 230.000 185.124 230.000 C 192.778 230.000,193.173 229.796,194.199 225.318 C 194.491 224.043,194.998 222.190,195.325 221.200 C 195.653 220.210,196.113 218.676,196.349 217.792 C 196.771 216.208,198.856 214.721,199.407 215.612 C 199.810 216.263,201.643 222.159,202.069 224.174 C 202.530 226.354,203.329 228.180,204.310 229.300 C 204.846 229.911,205.725 230.000,211.228 230.000 L 217.533 230.000 218.716 228.500 C 219.367 227.675,220.033 226.370,220.197 225.600 C 220.361 224.830,220.695 223.840,220.939 223.400 C 221.737 221.963,223.634 216.247,223.992 214.200 C 224.778 209.701,224.477 178.994,223.639 178.235 C 222.639 177.330,209.768 177.428,208.660 178.349 C 208.074 178.836,207.998 180.234,207.986 190.749 C 207.975 199.895,207.849 202.821,207.435 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 206.611 203.569 C 204.769 197.349,202.542 195.383,197.691 195.694 C 194.219 195.917,193.307 196.580,191.983 199.842 C 191.044 202.157,190.904 202.268,189.897 201.500 C 189.322 201.062,189.226 199.640,189.120 190.064 L 189.000 179.128 188.056 178.364 C 187.147 177.629,176.809 177.277,173.739 177.877 M234.373 178.233 C 233.536 179.241,233.513 228.332,234.349 229.339 C 234.844 229.935,236.605 230.000,252.360 230.000 L 269.823 230.000 272.641 228.649 C 277.851 226.152,278.543 224.243,278.334 212.929 C 278.178 204.508,278.085 204.270,273.702 201.043 L 271.215 199.213 272.183 197.787 C 276.427 191.533,273.913 181.449,267.378 178.516 C 264.969 177.435,235.247 177.180,234.373 178.233 M257.685 190.546 C 259.049 191.582,259.103 195.639,257.771 196.972 C 256.863 197.879,250.991 197.876,250.643 196.967 C 250.205 195.825,250.382 190.978,250.880 190.480 C 251.537 189.823,256.801 189.874,257.685 190.546 M261.463 210.219 C 262.188 211.210,262.167 215.618,261.433 216.624 C 260.703 217.623,251.345 218.071,250.751 217.135 C 250.336 216.479,250.299 210.777,250.706 210.140 C 251.474 208.940,260.576 209.006,261.463 210.219 " stroke="none" fill="#f4f4f4" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path1" d="M19.200 200.000 L 19.200 298.800 200.000 298.800 L 380.800 298.800 380.800 200.000 L 380.800 101.200 200.000 101.200 L 19.200 101.200 19.200 200.000 M162.618 178.582 L 163.600 179.564 163.600 198.702 C 163.600 223.682,163.323 224.863,156.608 228.550 C 150.057 232.147,134.482 232.241,127.469 228.726 C 122.318 226.144,120.847 222.981,120.517 213.783 C 120.075 201.449,120.081 201.441,129.244 201.660 C 136.770 201.840,136.400 201.519,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 215.403,137.245 216.643,142.170 216.330 C 146.506 216.053,146.181 217.583,146.319 196.789 L 146.438 178.806 147.519 178.219 C 149.618 177.080,161.399 177.363,162.618 178.582 M188.056 178.364 L 189.000 179.128 189.120 190.064 C 189.226 199.640,189.322 201.062,189.897 201.500 C 190.904 202.268,191.044 202.157,191.983 199.842 C 193.307 196.580,194.219 195.917,197.691 195.694 C 202.542 195.383,204.769 197.349,206.611 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 207.435 203.569 C 207.849 202.821,207.975 199.895,207.986 190.749 C 207.998 180.234,208.074 178.836,208.660 178.349 C 209.768 177.428,222.639 177.330,223.639 178.235 C 224.477 178.994,224.778 209.701,223.992 214.200 C 223.634 216.247,221.737 221.963,220.939 223.400 C 220.695 223.840,220.361 224.830,220.197 225.600 C 220.033 226.370,219.367 227.675,218.716 228.500 L 217.533 230.000 211.228 230.000 C 205.725 230.000,204.846 229.911,204.310 229.300 C 203.329 228.180,202.530 226.354,202.069 224.174 C 201.643 222.159,199.810 216.263,199.407 215.612 C 198.856 214.721,196.771 216.208,196.349 217.792 C 196.113 218.676,195.653 220.210,195.325 221.200 C 194.998 222.190,194.491 224.043,194.199 225.318 C 193.173 229.796,192.778 230.000,185.124 230.000 L 178.801 230.000 177.608 228.100 C 176.952 227.055,176.297 225.570,176.154 224.800 C 176.010 224.030,175.625 222.872,175.298 222.227 C 174.971 221.582,174.157 219.422,173.489 217.427 L 172.274 213.800 172.106 197.058 C 171.928 179.325,172.023 178.213,173.739 177.877 C 176.809 177.277,187.147 177.629,188.056 178.364 M267.378 178.516 C 273.913 181.449,276.427 191.533,272.183 197.787 L 271.215 199.213 273.702 201.043 C 278.085 204.270,278.178 204.508,278.334 212.929 C 278.543 224.243,277.851 226.152,272.641 228.649 L 269.823 230.000 252.360 230.000 C 236.605 230.000,234.844 229.935,234.349 229.339 C 233.513 228.332,233.536 179.241,234.373 178.233 C 235.247 177.180,264.969 177.435,267.378 178.516 M250.880 190.480 C 250.382 190.978,250.205 195.825,250.643 196.967 C 250.991 197.876,256.863 197.879,257.771 196.972 C 259.103 195.639,259.049 191.582,257.685 190.546 C 256.801 189.874,251.537 189.823,250.880 190.480 M252.000 209.470 C 250.586 209.768,250.412 210.219,250.412 213.600 C 250.412 217.817,250.237 217.693,255.978 217.535 C 261.781 217.375,262.000 217.224,262.000 213.400 C 262.000 209.745,261.702 209.506,256.963 209.372 C 254.783 209.311,252.550 209.355,252.000 209.470 " stroke="none" fill="#040404" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a very slight tweak to your css, you can achieve this without any need for javascript/jquery.  Adapt your css from `nav-item-active` to **`nav-item:active`** (using the pseudoclass), and the fill colour should change on click (view snippet to try it!)

New class code:

```
.nav-item:active .nav-item-background {
  fill: red;
}
```

```js
/*$('.nav-container li a').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.parent('li').addClass('nav-item-background').siblings('li').removeClass('nav-item-active');
});*/
```

```css
.nav-item .nav-item-background {
  fill: blue;
}

.nav-item:active .nav-item-background {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-container">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#0">
      <span>Home</span>
      <span>
<svg class="nav-item-background" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0, 0, 400,400"><g id="svgg"><path class="nav-item-background" id="path0" d="M147.519 178.219 L 146.438 178.806 146.319 196.789 C 146.181 217.583,146.506 216.053,142.170 216.330 C 137.245 216.643,136.400 215.403,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 201.519,136.770 201.840,129.244 201.660 C 120.081 201.441,120.075 201.449,120.517 213.783 C 120.847 222.981,122.318 226.144,127.469 228.726 C 134.482 232.241,150.057 232.147,156.608 228.550 C 163.323 224.863,163.600 223.682,163.600 198.702 L 163.600 179.564 162.618 178.582 C 161.399 177.363,149.618 177.080,147.519 178.219 M173.739 177.877 C 172.023 178.213,171.928 179.325,172.106 197.058 L 172.274 213.800 173.489 217.427 C 174.157 219.422,174.971 221.582,175.298 222.227 C 175.625 222.872,176.010 224.030,176.154 224.800 C 176.297 225.570,176.952 227.055,177.608 228.100 L 178.801 230.000 185.124 230.000 C 192.778 230.000,193.173 229.796,194.199 225.318 C 194.491 224.043,194.998 222.190,195.325 221.200 C 195.653 220.210,196.113 218.676,196.349 217.792 C 196.771 216.208,198.856 214.721,199.407 215.612 C 199.810 216.263,201.643 222.159,202.069 224.174 C 202.530 226.354,203.329 228.180,204.310 229.300 C 204.846 229.911,205.725 230.000,211.228 230.000 L 217.533 230.000 218.716 228.500 C 219.367 227.675,220.033 226.370,220.197 225.600 C 220.361 224.830,220.695 223.840,220.939 223.400 C 221.737 221.963,223.634 216.247,223.992 214.200 C 224.778 209.701,224.477 178.994,223.639 178.235 C 222.639 177.330,209.768 177.428,208.660 178.349 C 208.074 178.836,207.998 180.234,207.986 190.749 C 207.975 199.895,207.849 202.821,207.435 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 206.611 203.569 C 204.769 197.349,202.542 195.383,197.691 195.694 C 194.219 195.917,193.307 196.580,191.983 199.842 C 191.044 202.157,190.904 202.268,189.897 201.500 C 189.322 201.062,189.226 199.640,189.120 190.064 L 189.000 179.128 188.056 178.364 C 187.147 177.629,176.809 177.277,173.739 177.877 M234.373 178.233 C 233.536 179.241,233.513 228.332,234.349 229.339 C 234.844 229.935,236.605 230.000,252.360 230.000 L 269.823 230.000 272.641 228.649 C 277.851 226.152,278.543 224.243,278.334 212.929 C 278.178 204.508,278.085 204.270,273.702 201.043 L 271.215 199.213 272.183 197.787 C 276.427 191.533,273.913 181.449,267.378 178.516 C 264.969 177.435,235.247 177.180,234.373 178.233 M257.685 190.546 C 259.049 191.582,259.103 195.639,257.771 196.972 C 256.863 197.879,250.991 197.876,250.643 196.967 C 250.205 195.825,250.382 190.978,250.880 190.480 C 251.537 189.823,256.801 189.874,257.685 190.546 M261.463 210.219 C 262.188 211.210,262.167 215.618,261.433 216.624 C 260.703 217.623,251.345 218.071,250.751 217.135 C 250.336 216.479,250.299 210.777,250.706 210.140 C 251.474 208.940,260.576 209.006,261.463 210.219 " stroke="none" fill="#f4f4f4" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path1" d="M19.200 200.000 L 19.200 298.800 200.000 298.800 L 380.800 298.800 380.800 200.000 L 380.800 101.200 200.000 101.200 L 19.200 101.200 19.200 200.000 M162.618 178.582 L 163.600 179.564 163.600 198.702 C 163.600 223.682,163.323 224.863,156.608 228.550 C 150.057 232.147,134.482 232.241,127.469 228.726 C 122.318 226.144,120.847 222.981,120.517 213.783 C 120.075 201.449,120.081 201.441,129.244 201.660 C 136.770 201.840,136.400 201.519,136.400 207.862 C 136.400 215.403,137.245 216.643,142.170 216.330 C 146.506 216.053,146.181 217.583,146.319 196.789 L 146.438 178.806 147.519 178.219 C 149.618 177.080,161.399 177.363,162.618 178.582 M188.056 178.364 L 189.000 179.128 189.120 190.064 C 189.226 199.640,189.322 201.062,189.897 201.500 C 190.904 202.268,191.044 202.157,191.983 199.842 C 193.307 196.580,194.219 195.917,197.691 195.694 C 202.542 195.383,204.769 197.349,206.611 203.569 L 206.898 204.538 207.435 203.569 C 207.849 202.821,207.975 199.895,207.986 190.749 C 207.998 180.234,208.074 178.836,208.660 178.349 C 209.768 177.428,222.639 177.330,223.639 178.235 C 224.477 178.994,224.778 209.701,223.992 214.200 C 223.634 216.247,221.737 221.963,220.939 223.400 C 220.695 223.840,220.361 224.830,220.197 225.600 C 220.033 226.370,219.367 227.675,218.716 228.500 L 217.533 230.000 211.228 230.000 C 205.725 230.000,204.846 229.911,204.310 229.300 C 203.329 228.180,202.530 226.354,202.069 224.174 C 201.643 222.159,199.810 216.263,199.407 215.612 C 198.856 214.721,196.771 216.208,196.349 217.792 C 196.113 218.676,195.653 220.210,195.325 221.200 C 194.998 222.190,194.491 224.043,194.199 225.318 C 193.173 229.796,192.778 230.000,185.124 230.000 L 178.801 230.000 177.608 228.100 C 176.952 227.055,176.297 225.570,176.154 224.800 C 176.010 224.030,175.625 222.872,175.298 222.227 C 174.971 221.582,174.157 219.422,173.489 217.427 L 172.274 213.800 172.106 197.058 C 171.928 179.325,172.023 178.213,173.739 177.877 C 176.809 177.277,187.147 177.629,188.056 178.364 M267.378 178.516 C 273.913 181.449,276.427 191.533,272.183 197.787 L 271.215 199.213 273.702 201.043 C 278.085 204.270,278.178 204.508,278.334 212.929 C 278.543 224.243,277.851 226.152,272.641 228.649 L 269.823 230.000 252.360 230.000 C 236.605 230.000,234.844 229.935,234.349 229.339 C 233.513 228.332,233.536 179.241,234.373 178.233 C 235.247 177.180,264.969 177.435,267.378 178.516 M250.880 190.480 C 250.382 190.978,250.205 195.825,250.643 196.967 C 250.991 197.876,256.863 197.879,257.771 196.972 C 259.103 195.639,259.049 191.582,257.685 190.546 C 256.801 189.874,251.537 189.823,250.880 190.480 M252.000 209.470 C 250.586 209.768,250.412 210.219,250.412 213.600 C 250.412 217.817,250.237 217.693,255.978 217.535 C 261.781 217.375,262.000 217.224,262.000 213.400 C 262.000 209.745,261.702 209.506,256.963 209.372 C 254.783 209.311,252.550 209.355,252.000 209.470 " stroke="none" fill="#040404" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: I doubt OP is really looking for the actual `:active` pseudoclass behavior and not some sort of custom `active` class that retains the new state instead of reverting back upon mouse up

Comment: @AbanaClara OP can decide desired behaviour for themselves

Comment: Thanks guys!! I was looking to retain active state for the class, though I do like it's changing now instead of having to stare at the colors not changing :(